# Hashing file within DRF (POST HTTP request)

Tags: django, python-3.x, hash, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a REST API and I'm not particularly savvy in Django. I'd like to post an uploaded file, but before doing so I'd like to create the `sha256` of the file, like so:

```
def sha256sum(filename):
    h = hashlib.sha256()
    b = bytearray(128*1024)
    mv = memoryview(b)
    with open(filename, 'rb', buffering=0) as f:
        for n in iter(lambda : f.readinto(mv), 0):
            h.update(mv[:n])

    return h.hexdigest()
```

In order for this to work, I require the actual file (or file path), and not the actual filename. My code  in my viewsets.py:

```
def create(self, request):
    serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data) 
    f = request.FILES["file"] # just gives the filename
    print(request.META)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        f = serializer.save() 
        print(f"f: {f}")
        res_name = sha256sum(f)
        print(f"res_name: {res_name}")

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had request.FILES['file'] is a InMemoryUploadedFile.  After digging a bit dip  it appeared that this file was already  "open", so I just removed the open from my function, like so:

```
def sha256sum(filename):
    h = hashlib.sha256()
    b = bytearray(128*1024)
    mv = memoryview(b)
    for n in iter(lambda : filename.readinto(mv), 0):
        h.update(mv[:n])

    return h.hexdigest()
```